# Detecting Semantic Difference between Two Images

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis

I am seeking to determine if an edited version of an image has been edited so as to change semantic meaning.

To this end, I compute the cosine similarity between the two images under the embedding of openAI's CLIP. The problem: images edited in valid ways (eg simple brightness changes) show similar similarity scored (approx 0.9) to images with true semantic change (eg changing a frown to a smile), so this is clearly not enough. Wondering if anyone has ideas on how to leverage CLIP to detect "invalid" differences?

Comment: The cosine measure is an elementary statistic. It has nothing to do with the semantic content of an image. As if numbers could think !?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Certainly fair. Seeing much better success with more classical SIFT+ homography + pixel outlier detection after histogram normalization to find "semantic" change. I suppose I aspired for too much out of CLIP.

Comment: Neither SIFT nor other interest point types have any semantic meaning. Today only deep learning has some.

Comment: Certainly. The purpose of the algorithm is more to detect if there has been an edit that changes meaning, though, and not classify the change in meaning. Significant difference in interest points seem to correlate well with this.

Comment: How so ? Can you show an example ?